# Returning true/false after multiple functions

Tags: javascript

```
function topFunction() {
  if (checkUserRole()) {
    //trying to figure out if I will hit this line
  }
}

checkUserRole() {
  anotherFunction()
}

anotherFunction() {
  return true;
}
```

So what I am asking is, will that original `checkUserRole()` be considered true in this scenario? Or do I somehow need to pass the `true` up from `anotherFunction()` to `checkUserRole()`?

Comment: `checkUserRole()` will call `anotherFunction` but does not return any value, so it will implicitly return `undefined`, which is falsy, therefore won't go in the `if` body.

Comment: `return` statements do not cross function boundaries. Otherwise a caller of a function couldn't know what happens without knowing the implementation of the callee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to explicitly return it up:

```
function topFunction() {
  if (checkUserRole()) {
    //trying to figure out if I will hit this line
  }
}

checkUserRole() {
  return anotherFunction();
}

anotherFunction() {
  return true;
}
```

Without the return in the `checkUserRole` function the `true` that comes back from `anotherFunction` gets lost.  The way you had originally written it returns nothing from `checkUserRole`, which means that it will fail the "truthy" test in the if statement in `topFunction` no matter what happens in either `anotherFunction` or `checkUserRole`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Comment: Another related question, would you be able to add another function to this? So you would return anotherFunction() and then return yetAnotherFunction() below that in order to find the true/false?

Comment: You definitely can, take a look at this: https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the return statement inside the checkUserRole method